# Quotient in R to hold position in a matrix

Tags: matrix, position, modulo

Let's assume these are our numbers and we are looking for mod for them 
which we can find them using `library(pracma)`

```
> mod(c(1,4,23,13,8,9,11,27,32,2),7) 
> [1] 1 4 2 6 1 2 4 6 4 2
```

I want to get a number to see where each number is coming from when it is a matrix?

```
1,1,4,2,2,2,2,4,5,1
```

For example; if this is an m by 7 matrix;
We know that it is on 2nd column but what row? 9 is 2nd row (2,2) but not `quotient` is 1, then 23 is 4th row (4,2) but `quotient` is 3. Finally, last element 2 is on (1,2).

I am looking for **row position** since I can use the mod as a column position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came out with this

```
b=c(1,4,23,13,7,9,11,27,32,2)
floor(b/7+1)
[1] 1 1 4 2 2 2 2 4 5 1
```